# Importing bulk users in WSO2 is not working with some custom Claim URL and Value

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I prepared a csv file following the example below, however somehow for some claims I got an import error and they are not populated. By the manual creation procedure it works and they are correctly populated and saved. Is there something wrong with the claims configuration for bulk creation? Appreciate any help

Example:
UserName,Password,Claims,
chris2,chris123,http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress=dracusds123@gmail.com,http://wso2.org/claims/role=admin

I am expecting to create users importing the data from a csv file

Comment: Could you please mention the IS version that you tried? Also is the only above-given sample claim combination caused errors?

Comment: Also please provide the error stack trace printed in the terminal when you fail to import users from CSV filw.

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna
 IS 6.1.0 The real example that get an error is the following one, the error is only 'import error' and it occurs for the last claim without explanation.                                       
UserName,Password,Claims, MARIO, ROSSI, http://wso2.org/claims/givenName=MARIO,http://wso2.org/claims/lastname=ROSSI, http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress=mrossi@hotmail.com, http://wso2.org/claims/mobile=3496557704,http://wso2.org/claims/country=Agenzia,http://wso2.org/claims/businessCategory=NA

Comment: Checked the same with IS 6.1.0. The only pre-requisite was to add the businessCategory as a local claim. 

I tried with the csv attached, and there were few formatting issues. Could you check if this is due to the format of the csv?

Comment: @GoushiRam I tried with several format like UTF8, MSDOS and standard csv however nothing changes. Is there any specific format I should use?

Comment: At the end I was able to run the bulk creation, the issue was with some Claims not correctly mapped. Thanks to everyone for the support